# Возможна ли реализация PUSH-уведомлений без защищеного соединения?

Tags: javascript, https, уведомления, push

Хочу реализовать PUSH-уведомления на локальном сайте. В консоли выводится сообщение об ошибке: **"Разрешение на отправку уведомлений может быть предоставлено только при защищённом соединении."**

В интернете во всех источниках, посвященных PUSH, пишут, что без HTTPS реализация уведомлений невозможна.

У меня два вопроса:

1.Почему реализация PUSH невозможна без защищенного соединения (не нашел информации о причинах)?

2.Нет ли какой-либо возможности обойти данное ограничение? Разрабатываемый мною сервис будет применяться локально, установка защищенного соединения не представляется возможной.

Comment: Почему не представляется возможной? Есть же самоподписные сертификаты. Сам не пробовал, но тут пишут [Mkcert: валидные HTTPS-сертификаты для localhost](https://habr.com/ru/company/globalsign/blog/435476/), вдруг поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реализация PUSH невозможна без защищенного соединения. Потому что...

Перевод абзаца из документации [PUSH API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/#security-and-privacy-considerations):

> User agents MUST implement the Push API to only be available in a
> secure context. This provides better protection for the user against
> man-in-the-middle attacks intended to obtain push subscription data.

"Юзер-агенты ОБЯЗАНЫ сделать реализацию Push API доступной только в защищенной среде. Это обеспечивает защиту от атаки man-in-the-middle, ориентированной на получение данных о подписке на push-уведомления."

В общем, речь про защиту от спама (в первую очередь фишинга, когда мошеннические пуши будут выглядеть, как настоящие, ведь они как раз будут настоящими) и потенциального хищения персональных данных.

Возможно, стоит обратить внимание на самоподписные сертификаты. Потенциально полезный материал [Mkcert: валидные HTTPS-сертификаты для localhost](https://habr.com/ru/company/globalsign/blog/435476/).

Comment: спасибо за ответ!